# Is there any abelian group whose Schur multiplier is $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am working at some problem related to non abelian exterior square $G\wedge G$ of a finite abelian group $G$. My question is that:

> Is there any abelian group whose Schur multiplier is $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$.

It is well known that Schur multiplier of $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$ is $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and Schur multiplier of $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$ is $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$ itself. Then for which abelian group $G$, $M(G)$ will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: Are you talking about finite abelian groups or all abelian groups? The answer is no for finite abelian groups, but I  do not know whether there are any infinite examples. Finite abelian groups are direct products of cyclic groups (which have trivial multiplier), and $M(G \times H) \cong M(G) \times M(H) \times G \otimes H$. You can use that to show that there are no finite examples.

Comment: Please edit your previous question rather than post separately an immediate related variation.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your responce.